# Most efficient way of converting byte array to vector

Tags: opencl

What is the most efficient way of converting an array of 16 bytes into
a uint4 vector ? currently, I manually OR the bytes into uints, then set
the vector's components with the completed uints. Is there OpenCL support for performing this task?

This is for OpenCL 1.2

Edit: here is my code:

```
    local uchar buffer[16];
    uint v[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        v[i]=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            v[i] |= (buffer[(i<<2)+j]) << (j<<3);
        }
    }
    uint4 result = (uint4)(v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3]);
```

Edit 2: buffer is actually a local buffer.

Comment: Please show your code. As far as I understand this question no conversion is required at all. Reinterpreting the bytes should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, duly edited.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to convert it on the fly without copying the data:

```
local uchar buffer[16];
if(get_local_id(0) == 0)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x)
    {
        buffer[x] = x + 1;
        buffer[x + 4] = x + 2;
        buffer[x + 8] = x + 3;
        buffer[x + 12] = x + 4;
    }
    local uint4 *result = (local uint4*)buffer;
    printf("0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x\n", (*result).x, (*result).y, (*result).z, (*result).w);
}
```

Result:

```
0x4030201 0x5040302 0x6050403 0x7060504
```

If you need to copy the data though you do:

```
uint4 result = *(local uint4*)buffer;
```

Comment: Thanks, doqtor. I originally had this, but I was getting errors. The buffer is actually a local buffer; I've updated the question to reflect this.  So, casting a local buffer seems to be a no-no.

Comment: Your answer also assumes little endian arch.

Comment: @Jacko I've updated my answer to reflect the fact that this is a local buffer.

Comment: @Jacko re endianess: the dominant CPU and GPU architectures all default to LE.

Comment: Yes, true enough about endian.  But, casting local buffers did not work for me.

Comment: @Jacko What exactly did not work? did not compile, did return wrong results, something else? Have you tried copy-paste my example? What gpu are you using?

Comment: Yes it did compile. I tested passing an array of 16 bytes, and then casting to an array of unsigned int:  the data was not correct after casting. One thing: the pointer was pass into my method using the restrict keyword, so perhaps this is why I had problems after cast.

Answer (score 1):

If you shape your data in a different way you have an instruction for that:

```
ushort[n] upsample (uchar[n] hi, uchar[n] lo){
    result[i]= ((short)hi[i]<< 8) | lo[i]
}
uint[n] upsample (ushort[n] hi, ushort[n] lo){
    result[i]= ((uint)hi[i]<< 8) | lo[i]
}
```

But you will need `uchar16 buffer' = (uchar16)(buffer[0], buffer[4], buffer[8], buffer[12], buffer[1], buffer[5], buffer[9], buffer[13], ....)` (please check!)

In order to be able to just perform a simple:

```
uint4 result = upsample(upsample(buffer'));
```

This is probably the fastest way of doing it, since it does vector operations.
If you have the data properly shaped of course....

---

But if your data is aligned, you can just cast it, and it will work.

```
uint4 result = *((local uint4 *)(&buffer));
```

For your case I think it is not, so you can do something like:

```
uchar16 bufferR = (uchar16)(buffer[3], buffer[2], buffer[1], buffer[0], buffer[7], buffer[6], buffer[5], buffer[4], ....)
uint4 result = *((uint4 *)(&bufferR));
```

Or maybe align it in the portion of code that creates that block of `uchar16`

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me more about how to align the buffer?  This is actually a local buffer, if that makes a difference. I found that casting the buffer caused errors.

Comment: You can cast any type in OpenCL, as long as the memory region type matches. If it is a local buffer, then you can only cast it to a local pointer. However, if you shape the data first to a private register, it should work. It is the last piece of code in my answer. You copy the data to a private member (bufferR) doing the reshape, and then you can just cast it to uint4 since it is already a private register.

Comment: Thanks, man. In the end, I chose the safe route that didn't need any casting.