# How may I convert/cast scalar to vector (and vice versa) in OpenCL

Tags: c, types, casting, opencl, type-conversion

How can I convert a 16-element scalar to a single vector in OpenCL?

```
char[16] scalar = .. .. .. ;

char16 vectr = scalar;         //do conversion/casting here.
```

I have this,

```
char16 vectr = (char16) (scalar[0], scalar[1], scalar[2] ... scalar[15]);
```

but there should be a more efficient way?

And, how to better convert the vector back to scalar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952315/most-efficient-way-of-converting-byte-array-to-vector

Comment: can't you use vload()?

Answer (score 2):

You've got 2 options:

**1. Use a union. This is explicitly allowed as per section 6.2.4.1 in the OpenCL standard.**

Something like:

```
union my_type
{
  char scalar[16];
  char16 vector;
};
```

The advantage of this is that the alignment will definitely be correct.

The disadvantage is that indexing into variable length arrays with this is awkward.

This makes it more practical for data stored in `__local` and `__private`, which is often fixed-size anyway.

**2. You can cast between pointers to the scalar vs vector types.**

The vector types are considered to be aggregate types with members of their scalar types, so such casts would even be allowed without the relaxation of the reinterpreting rules in OpenCL compared to C. (see 6.1.8, 6.2.5)

This code:

```
char16 vec = (char16)(1, 2, 3, …);
char* scalar = (char*)&vec;
```

Is perfectly valid.

Advantage: convenient.

Disadvantage: easy to get wrong - especially with regard to forgetting the correct address space qualifier or not meeting implicit alignment requirements.

Finally, you're presumably aware that you can access elements of the built-in vector types, e.g. using `vectr.s3` and similar? Often this allows you to just use the vector types throughout without the need for switching between vector and array types.

(I'm referring to v1.2 of the standard.)

Answer (score 2):

There is also the **3rd** way: use built-in function(s) (actually, macro) `as_typen()` and `as_type()`.